# Error invoking bsh method:....Error in method invocation: Method createCa( int ) not found in class'cacreator.CaCreator'

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am pretty new to Jmeter tool and I am trying to use my own java class to call a function in BeanShell Pre-Processor.
I have written a Java programme and packaged it into a .jar file and copied it into the /lib/ext folder where the Jmeter is installed.
Here is my java class snippet:

```
package cacreator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaCreator {

static  String Name = "\"Name\" : 11";
static  String AppName = "\"ApplicationGroup\" : \"qa\"";
static  String caValues = ""; // = "[{";

public static String createCa(int count)
{

    for (int vCount = 1; vCount <= count; vCount++) {
        caValues = caValues.concat( "\n" + "{ \n" + Name + ", \n\"Value\" : \"" + vCount+300 + "\",\n" + AppName + "\n}");
        if(vCount != count)
        {
            caValues = caValues.concat(",");
           // caValues = caValues.concat("\"Name\" : \"Test");
        }
    }
    return caValues;
}
```

and the code for BeanShell Pre-Processor:

```
import cacreator.CaCreator;
CaCreator obj1 = new CaCreator();
int firstParam = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[0]);
String outPut = obj1.createCa(firstParam);
vars.put("ca", outPut);
```

i am getting the following errors:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import cacreator.CaCreator; CaCreator obj1 = new CaCreator(); int firstParam = I . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method createCa( int ) not found in class'cacreator.CaCreator'
WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import cacreator.CaCreator; CaCreator obj1 = new CaCreator(); int firstParam = I . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method createCa( int ) not found in class'cacreator.CaCreator'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: method createCa is static, so it belongs to class, not to object: `CaCreator.createCa(firstParam );` or remove `static` keyword from function definition.

Comment: Got it resolved.. I had to copy my .jar file to jmeter/lib and not jmeter/lib/ext

Answer (score 0):

You need to put jar in jmeter/lib folder not jmeter/lib/ext.

Also since your method is static, you can simplify your code this way:

```
import cacreator.CaCreator;
int firstParam = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[0]);
String outPut = CaCreator.createCa(firstParam);
vars.put("ca", outPut);
```